# Is it possible to only convert the values and format of a Microsoft excel spreadsheet to a google spreadsheet (so not the formulas)?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I need to convert a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet to a google spreadsheet, but the Excel sheet is made by linking to external data, which I have no access to. The values are still visible on the Excel sheet. When I import the Excel sheet to google drive and convert to a google spreadsheet, all values are '#REF!' because it can't of course find the source of the data. I can copy/paste the values from Excel to a new google spreadsheet, but that destroys the formatting. So is there a way to copy format and values from an Excel sheet to google spreadsheet, preferably with google apps script so that I can automate it. (it has to be done on a daily basis)

Answer (score 2):

You should use Excel itself, to replace the formula linked values with plain values first. You can then import that excel file into google drive if required. Here's a link from Microsoft showing you how to do it: [replace formula with values](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-a-formula-with-its-result-38001951-c0e8-4fbd-9048-37ef81e2891e)

Comment: The OP was looking for an automated / scripted way that involves no GUI / user interaction.   So am I.   ;-)